# IE9 only font-face issue (rendering fallback font)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts, internet-explorer-9

The site works fine on chrome and the latest version of ff. It also appears to work fine and display the correct font on IE8; However in IE9 it is displaying a bolder font.

```
 @font-face{
    font-family: 'effraregular';
    src: url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/assets/effra_std_rg-webfont.eot");
    src: url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/assets/effra_std_rg-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
    url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/assets/effra_std_rg-webfont.woff") format('woff'),
    url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/assets/effra_std_rg-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),
    url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/assets/effra_std_rg-webfont.svg#effraregular") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face{
    font-family: 'effralight';
    src: url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.eot");
    src: url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
    url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.woff") format('woff'),
    url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),
    url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.svg#effralight") format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

According to another question, it would seem the fix is to change format from eot, to embedded-opentype however as you can see this has already been done.

the font family being used in the document:

font-family 'effralight','effraregular' it appears that in IE9, it is using the fallback font effraregular (if I live edit effraregular to remove it, it defaults to times new roman or something similar).

doctype:
     `<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">`

Comment: Lacking essential information: HTML and CSS code, source of the font, the real addresses used to access the fonts, etc.

Comment: Hey i cant seem to get it work even on FF/Chrome ~ check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8kV5v/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a `meta` tag into your HTML as a quick workaround, which will tell `IE9` to emulate `IE8`, bringing back the original rendering. or for [**more information on same**](http://www.fiveforblogger.com/2011/12/google-webfont-and-bold-text-issue-ie9.html)

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />` in your  section.

But with this you have to compromise with other `IE9` features like the better `HTML5` and `CSS3` support.

Generally, when you tell `IE9` to render font as `bold`, the required switch will happen for `font-weight`s of `800` and `900`.

or use

```css
font-family: 'effralight';
    src: url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.eot");
    src: url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'),
    url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.woff") format('woff'),
    url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.ttf") format('truetype'),
    url("http://www.xxxx.com.au/images/assetimages/fonts/effra_light-webfont.svg#effralight") format('svg');
font-size: 0.75em;  
font-weight: 700;
```

Even using **[nomalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)** may help you in the same